# Multiplying the imaginary part of DFT with a linear ramp to get a derivative

Tags: fourier-transform, dft, finite-differences

I am trying to understand the statement in a relatively old publication from 1970s, when Fourier transforms found applications in chemical analysis. The author quotes the derivative theorem citing Bracewell of 1965 (I could not locate this *exact* statement in later edition of Bracewell).

Edits: As discussed in the comments, the approach as literally suggested does not work universally for example a Gaussian peak will have zero imaginary parts. However the idea is neat to differentiate *experimental data* while filtering the noise.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's an inconsistency between the plots and the quotation. If your ultimate goal is to obtain a *differentiated Fourier spectrum*, then you should multiply the time-domain signal by a ramp, but the quotation implies multiplying teh Freuqency spectrum by a ramp, which however, equates to a differentiated time-domain signal. And furthermore, I think you are aware that the mentioned theorem is stated for continuous-time signals, whereas you are probably using discrete-time sequence and its continuous-freq Fourier spectrum.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am trying to do. I have to get a derivative shape in the time domain of a time domain signal using the method suggested the author. Basically, I am trying to replicate what he is saying. He was a very respected person from my former university and he says the same in another book. He says that differentiation is basically a high pass filter in the frequency domain. What do you understand by his quote and his old picture? Do you think they are wrong? We cannot reproduce what is suggesting.

Comment: New quotation, makes it clear where the *differentiation* takes place, the time-domain. But again the plots refer to *spectrum* being differentiated, duality can be applied to get the same effect in frequency. Anyway, let me put a possile interpretation.

Comment: Let me clarify the chemical perspective. The x-axis of the original two peaks must be wavelength (knowing the background of the author Gary Horlick). This is a spectrum of Na atoms, showing the intensity of the wavelengths. The x-axis must have units of [Length]. Now he Fourier transforms it. Applies a ramp function plus cut-off to the imaginary part and gets a derivative shape back in the wavelength domain.

Comment: Right Ed, I have implemented what Bracewell and Cooper successfully with some slight modifications. I am saying what Gary suggests, if followed *literally*, it does not work (i.e., to use imaginary part only). Fat32 applied the ramp on the entire real and imaginary part. Tom could not reproduce Gary's suggestion either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've changed my mind during the answer. Instead of using frequency domain processing to get the *derivative* signal, I will provide a more direct and clean approach to get the derivative of a signal by using what's called a *digital-differentiator*.  An LTI filter, which is applied into the samples $x[n]$ of a signal $x(t)$ and computes the samples $y[n]$ of the derivative $y(t) = x(t)'$ of $x(t)$.

Below is the matlab code you can use to compute the samples of the derivative of a bandlimited signal $x(t)$:

```
N = 512;                   % length of x[n]; samples of signal x(t).

% Assume Gaussian pulses added:
t = linspace(-1,1-2/N,N);  % time is sampled at T = 2/N period.

sigma = 0.001;             % Gaussian pulse shape parameter (adjust accordingly)
x1 = 2*exp(-(t.^2)/(2*sigma) );         % Gaussian pulse one
x2 = 0.5*exp(-((t-0.5).^2)/(3*sigma) ); % Gaussian pulse two
x = x1 + x2;               % total signal


% Generate differentiator impulse response hc[n]:
T = 2/N;                  % sampling period (implicit, defined above)
n = -N/2:N/2;
h = ((-1).^n)./(n*T);
h(N/2+1) = 0;
w = hamming(2*N/2+1)';
hc = w.*h;                % causal,stable impulse response hc[n]


% Filter x[n] to compute samples of derivative signal
y = conv(x,hc);
yd = y(N/2+1:N/2+N);     % extract relevant portion

% display the result:
figure,plot(t,x);
hold on
plot(t,0.1*yd);
legend('x(t)','dx/dt');
grid on
title('x(t) vs dx(t)/dt  (scale adjusted to fit both');
```

The result is :

[image]

For getting the same result using DFT techniques,
the following code can be used :

```
M = N+N;
H = fft(hc,M);          % generate the RAMP mask to apply on X(w)
Y = fft(x,M).*H;        % obtain ramp multiplication in freq domain
y = real(ifft(Y,M));    % invert back to time domain
y = y(N/2+1:N/2+N);     % extract relevant portions

figure,subplot(2,1,1)
plot(linspace(0,2,M),abs(H)); title('RAMP mask that is applied on X(w) in freq-domain')

subplot(2,1,2)
plot(t,x);
hold on
plot(t,0.1*y);
legend('x(t)','dx/dt');
grid on
title('x(t) vs dx(t)/dt  (amplitude scale adjusted)');
```

with exactly the same result on the time-domain sequence as shown below:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your time and answer but really wanted to see what Gary Horlick (quoted text in OP) is trying to do using his ramp approach and why it is not working on a Gaussian pulse. He is for sure using discrete data in his chapter.

Comment: No It works.... Let meadd that *esoteric* piece of code too...

Comment: Thanks for showing the ramp mask and you have shown the convolution vs. multiplication property. I still feel that Gary is not right somewhere. He is only focusing on the imaginary part of the Fourier transform of the signal. Then he multiplies it with a ramp. Inverse transforms it, gets the real part of it and says that it is shaped like a derivative. I feel if we follow his suggestion literally, it does not work.

Comment: Is there a simple way to generate a ramp mask in MATLAB without knowing the time domain filter?

Comment: @M.Farooq I see your comments on applying the algorithm to only imaginary part only. The paper is **correct**: You must apply even/odd **symmetry** properties of the Fourier transforms to get the result.

Comment: Yes, for example for the FT of pure Gaussian, the imaginary part is zero. So his suggestion does not apply. Spectroscopic peaks are usually Lorentzian.

Comment: @M.Farooq I've finally added what you wanted to learn, in the new answer.

Answer (score 3):

From your comments, it look as if you want to **manually** create the ramp mask, and apply it in the frequency-domain so as to achieve the result of differentiation in time-domain.

Considering the ideal continuous-time differentiator frequency response as:

$$ H(\Omega) = j \Omega \tag{1}$$

we shall use the approach of *discrete-time processing of continuous-time systems*, and obtain its discrete-time effective frequency response as :

$$ H(\omega) = j \omega/T_s ~~~,~~~ -\pi < \omega < \pi \tag{2}$$

which yields a bandlimited discrete-time approximation to the true ideal continuous-time infinite bandwidth differentiator. Where $T_s$ is the sampling period of the digital system. The associated bandwidth of the approximated continuous-time analog differentiator is $B = \pi/T_s = \pi F_s = \Omega_s/2$ in radians/second.

Then in the discrete-time domain, you can generate samples $x[n]$ (approximately) bandlimited signals, such as the Gaussian pulse with proper parameters. assuming that the DTFT of $x[n]$ is $X(\omega)$, then the following procedure produces samples $y[n]$ of the bandlimited derivative $y(t)=x(t)'$ of $x(t)$.

$$Y(\omega) = H(\omega) \cdot X(\omega) = j\omega X(w) \tag{3}$$

The associated samples $y[n]$ can be obtained by the invere DTFT of $Y(\omega)$. The rest is programming logic, as I have provided a sample below. Note that the linear ramp values should be generated by considering the **phase** of the ideal requirement vs phase of the practical implementation. In particular, my definition refers to the ideal non-causal filter and signal models.

One note about your concern on the application of this method: it applies on the complete DTFT $X(\omega)$ of $x[n]$. However, if $x[n]$ has an even-symmetry (or equivalently its DFT frame has periodic-even symmetry), then the DTFT of $x[n]$ will be real and even; i.e., imaginary part of its DTFT will be zero. Similary if $h[n]$ has odd symmetry (which indeed is the case) then its DFT will be purely imaginary. Then the multiplication in Eq.3 becomes :

$$Y(\omega) = j\omega \cdot (X_r(w) + jX_i(\omega)) = -j\omega \cdot X_r(w) \tag{4}$$

Hence effectively, you are applying the ramp mask to the real part of the DTFT of the input. Furthermore, since that product is purely imaginary, it corresponds to the imaginary part of the DTFT of an odd sequence $y[n]$. However, if $x[n]$ lacks the required even-symmetry, then the result won't hold true. I don't know if the author of that paper you refer to, indicates the conditions on his application of this theorem.

```
% S0 - Define Parameters :
% ------------------------
K = 80;             % 
N = 2*K+1;          % length of frame

Ts = 0.01;          % sampling period
n  = -K:K;          % sequence range (non-causal)


% S1 - Generate Input Sequence :
% ------------------------------
% Gaussian Pulse
sigma = 0.001;
t1 = (n+15)*Ts;
t2 = (n-15)*Ts;
x = exp(-t1.^2 / (2*sigma));        % 1 - original non-causal samples.
x = x + 0.5*exp(- t2.^2 / (3*sigma));



% S3 - Generate ideal samples of the theoretical derivative y(t) of x(t) :
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
% x(t) = exp(-t^2 / (2*sigma)) => y(t) = x(t)' = -(t/sigma)*exp(-t^2/(2*sigma))  
% x[n] = x(n*Ts)               => y[n] = y(n*Ts);
%

yi = -(t1/sigma).*exp(-t1.^2/(2*sigma)) ;      % 1 - ideal noncausal samples of y(t)
yi = yi - 0.5*2*t2/(3*sigma) .* exp(-t2.^2/(3*sigma));


% S4 - MANUALLY generate the M-point DFT samples of the ideal differentiator:
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
M = 2*N-1;                          % M = min DFT length, K = N-1 in this case

Hce = 1j * (2*pi/M)*[0:M-1];        % Ideal diff.filter H(w) = j*w  -pi < w < pi
                                    % Periodic extension to 0< w < 2*pi requires
Hce(N+1:M) = Hce(N+1:M) - 1j*2*pi;  % -j*2*pi subtracted from the second half.
                                    % This frequency response Hce corresponds to
                                    % the TRUE samples of the non-causal impulse
                                    % response h[n] = (-1)^n/n , for n=[-K:K]*Ts
                                    %
                                    % Hce[k] = M-DFT{ hce[n] }
                                    
                                    
% S5 - Apply filtering in frequency-domain :
% ------------------------------------------
% extent h[n] and x[n] into frame of M samples
xM = fCirShift(x,M,K);              % The circular extension ensures that the
hceM = fCirShift(h,M,K);            % DFT of new samples still corresponds to
                                    % the TRUE samples of non-causal x[n]/h[n].
                                    % so that Hce[k] = M-DFT{ hce[n] }

y = real( ifft( Hce.* fft(xM,M) , M ) )/Ts;
y = fCirShift(y,M,-K);              % Shift right by K = N/2, to bring relevant
y = y(1:N);                         % samples into n = 0:N-1; and extract so.


% S6 - Display the result :
% -------------------------
t = Ts*n;

figure, plot(t,x) ; title('samples x[n] of x(t)');

figure, plot( t, x , 'b', t, yi ,'ro-', t, y , 'g+-');
legend('x[n]','yi[n]','y[n]');
title('samples of x(t), ideal derivative yi(t), and computed derivative y(t)');

figure, stem(t,yi-y);title('yi[n]-y[n] : difference between ideal and computed');
```

The resulting plots are  as follows:

the signal,

[image]

the derivative,

[image]

the error,

[image]

Comment: +1 Thank you for you details again. I think we all agree now that the suggestion by the author is not universal. However his idea to use a ramp+cut-off is nice simple idea. As a chemist, most people like myself won't be comfortable with circular shifts with practical data. I also attempted a manual ramp that works pretty perfectly up to the 10th derivative but gives a wrong magnitude. It turned out that I was not dividing by the time interval.

Comment: @M.Farooq Yes the *restriction* into *only imaginary* part of FT is not universal. Rather one should use the main idea of *differentiation in time-domain equals multiplication by $j\omega$ in frequency-domain*. which is universal:  if $$x(t) \longleftrightarrow X(\omega) $$ then $$x(t)' \longleftrightarrow j\omega X(\omega) $$ Which forms the basis property for converting a LCCDE into frequency domain for algebraic solution.

Comment: @M.Farooq And by the way, the *diff()* function you have used, is not a replacement for the true derivative $dx(t)/dt$ that we computed above. Rather, it's a very crude approximation given by the *first difference* (or the m-th difference) : diff(x[n]) = x[n+1]-x[n]. This difference, when divided by $T_s$ (the sampling interval) gives a crude approximation to the rate-of-change (aka slope) of the function $x(t)$ around the point $t= n T_s$. **But** the algorithm that I have implemented gives a much more accurate approximation (indeed ideally exact) of the true derivate $dx(t)/dt$ at $t=nT_s$.

Comment: Yes, I was discussing the issues with numerical derivatives by difference method with mathematicians https://mathoverflow.net/questions/378434/numerically-differentiated-values-and-their-corresponding-x-coordinates?noredirect=1#comment960897_378434

Comment: There is another implementation of derivatives by FT method that avoids ringing. It also works pretty well. See this paper in Google Scholar "Calculating numerical derivatives using Fourier transform: some pitfalls and how to avoid them". It involves a built in sinc function multiplier to reduce noise and ringing.

Comment: @M.Farooq Do you remember the **Mean Value theorem** from Calculus-I. According to which: for any *differentiable* function $x(t)$ on the closed interval $t \in [a,b]$, there exists at least one value $c \in [a,b]$, anywhere in the interval, such that $$x(c)' = \frac{x(b)-x(a)}{b-a} \tag{1}$$ Replace $a,b$ with $(n-1)T_s$ and $nT_s$, then the theorem reads: $$x(c)' = \frac{x[n]-x[n-1]}{T_s} \tag{2}$$ Which indicates that the **exact location** of the derivative indicated by the RHS of Eq.2 is **unknown** somewhere in between $[a,b]$ interval. So you cannot use **diff()** method to guess it.

Comment: @M.Farooq However, in the Fourier method that I presented above, which (approximately) implements the *ideal bandlimited differentiation* of a bandlimited signal $x(t)$ through processing its samples $x[n]$ by a filter $h[n]$ (either by convolving with it in time-domain, or manually masking with the linear ramp in the freq-domain), the exact time of the derivative samples is known to be $ n T_s$; every sample of the derivative signal is taken at $t = n T_s$ so that $y[n]=x'(t)|_{t=nT_s}$...

Comment: Right, this is why I am beginning to like this FT method because experimental data is always noisy and even at second derivative it begins to become noisy like crazy. We also don't get the issue of having less and less points after every differentiation. Gary's method is neat in the sense differentiation and filtering is done at the same time in a single step. I am using a right triangle and still it works pretty well.

Comment: @M.Farooq Hmm, now I see why you set the second half of the ramp to zero... So you wanted to merge the lowpass filter with the differentiator... ;-) That's economic for basic noise reduction. There's also the concept of Savitzky-Golay filtering for polynomial fit based noise reduction you can apply before differentiation. You seem to have delved quite deep into signal processing !

Comment: Yes, without taking a single course in DSP :-( It is difficult and sometime elementary things bother a lot but it is rewarding in the end. Thanks to SE groups and their volunteers. I would have given up this triangular pulse if you had not shown it by a figure and confirmed that we need both real and imaginary part. Gary Horlick was a respected professor in the 1970-80s who did a lot of work in signal processing for spectroscopic analysis. But here was partially incorrect here!

Comment: @M.Farooq I searched Gary Horlick now; it seems he was kind of a legend back then. So I don't think so he would make such simple error in his papers. He probably have referenced the details to some other papers, and mentions the general outline, rather than giving specifically an explicit algorithm. Anyway, I don't have access to them (don't have time to read too). Nevertheless, it's also possible that the statement *literally* could be incorrect...

Comment: In the original paper, he only cited Bracewell. But everyone makes mistakes in interpretation.